# Refresh Page twice during Click - Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sharepoint

I'm developing a Webpage with ASP.NET and C# as code behind. 
I have a page with a button that should trigger an event to refresh or rerender the page 2 times and to start an SQL query: 1 is to make the GUI inactive while the SQL query is running, and 2 refresh or rerender to switch back to normal GUI.

I've tried it with Response.Redirect, so the page does a PostBack and in Page_Load - Event I check the isGUInactive variable. If true, the GUI will be disabled until the SQL query is finished, then I make another refresh and set isGUIinactive to true, so the GUI will be enabled in another PostBack in the Page_Load - Event.
But Response.Redirect doesn't work this way. It waits until button_Click method is finished, then doing a PostBack.
Could you provide me any alternatives to let my page refresh or rerender twice to accomplish my goal?

```
private void button_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{  
   isGUIinactive = true; // Disable GUI
   Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false); // Disable GUI in PostBack

   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      {
          connection.Open();

          SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlcomm, connection);
          command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          dt.Load(reader);
          BindData(dt); // Bind Data to GridView
      }
   isGUIinactive = false; // Enable GUI
   Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false); // Enable GUI in PostBack
}
```

**Update:**

ASP:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"  %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint"  Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="GUIUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Project.GUI.GUIUserControl" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<script type="text/javascript">
  function lockGUI() {
      var blocking_div = "<div style='" +
            "position:fixed;" +
            "width:100%;" +
            "height:100%;" +
            "left:0;" +
            "top:0;" +
            "background-color:#444455;" +
            "color:white;" +
            "text-align:center;font-size:20px;" +
            "'>Loading</div>";
      var GUIPanel = document.getElementById("block_div");
      GUIPanel.style["visibility"] = "hidden";
      document.body.innerHTML += blocking_div;

  }

    </script>

<body>

<div id="block_div" style="background-color:White;">

// Big GridView

<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BorderWidth="0px" Width="233px" 
Height="16px">
<asp:TableRow ID="Tr1" runat="server" >
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false"  ID="btnsynchro" runat="server" Text="synchronize table" 
OnClick="btnsynchro_Click" OnClientClick="lockGUI();" />
    </asp:TableCell>

    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Button ID="btntest" runat="server" Text="for testing" 
        onclick="btntest_Click"/>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>

  </asp:Table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
protected void btnsynchro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
      connection.Open();

      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlcomm, connection);
      command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Load(reader);
      BindData(dt); // Bind Data to GridView
  }
 Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false);
}
```

Comment: well first of all, when you do a response redirect, the rest of the code wont execute

Comment: if u want to disable the gui, use partial page rendering. you can achieve it with control panel.

Comment: Are you escaping the javascript??? You seem trying to do all the job through c#  on the server

Comment: @Banana you're right, updated my question, forgot to add parameters.

Comment: @user3453011 stackunderflow is right, you should use javascript to achieve optimal results. ill try to write you some neat example if i get some time

Comment: @Banana thanks for that, i'm doing some research on partial page rendering right now. I'm not that experienced with javascript.

Comment: sure. partial page rendering can be done with ajax, it basically means that you send an http get request behind the scenes, get the new data and paste it into your page without reloading. asp.net implements ajax using update panel and script manager, can be found in visual studio toolbox under ajax extensions. id recommend doing ajax without the update panel, but the panel is good for beginning

Comment: sorry for the late reply, ive wrote you an example, see below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright so here goes:

basically a simple solution would be to call a javascript function to disable the GUI, after which to perform the asp.net click.

its easily done by a `onClientClick` attribute, it calls a javascript function after which the OnClick is executed.

ive made an example, it has one page page Default.aspx, in this example i hide the gui div and put a blocking div all over the page:

html:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function lockGUI() {
            var blocking_div = "<div style='" +
                "position:fixed;" +
                "width:100%;" +
                "height:100%;" +
                "left:0;" +
                "top:0;"+
                "background-color:#444455;" +
                "color:white;" +
                "text-align:center;"+
                "'>Loading, Please wait.</div>";
            var GUIPanel = document.getElementById("UI_DIV");
            GUIPanel.style["visibility"] = "hidden";
            document.body.innerHTML += blocking_div;

        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" id="TheForm">
   <div id="UI_DIV" style="background-color:red;">
       this is the ui 
       <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="lockGUI();" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
   </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
             //just a codeblock to make it load long, replace with yours.
        }
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

if you have any questions, feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you very much, but it seems that my OnClick -Event is being ignored because of the OnClientClick -Event

Comment: yes indeed my friend, this is exactly the reason for `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`  put it in, and your click even will be executed

Comment: Thank you, but I already included this snippet: <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false"  ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Text" 
    OnClick="btn1_Click" OnClientClick="lockGUI()" />
The script executed properly and locked the whole GUI.

Comment: and your OnClick is simply being ignored ?

Comment: can you put a breakpoint in your click handler and see if maybe the code there simply fails?

Comment: Yes, my onclick is being ignored, I put a breakpoint in my onclick and debugging it, but it isn't event going there. Without the OnClientClick - event, the onclick - event executed.

Comment: did you use the exact code i posted? it is possible that in your onClientClick you accidentally remove the asp button, maybe replace the div's html and the button gets removed, in which case it will not execute the OnClick either

Comment: To be honest, I had to remove the head, title and form tag, because I got exceptions from them. E.g. "A page can have only one server-side Form tag"

Comment: yea asp can only have one serverside form, but do you remove the button in your javascript function?

Comment: I think not: 
<script type="text/javascript">
function lockGUI() {
var blocking_div = "<div style='" +
 "position:fixed;" +
  "width:100%;" +
   "height:100%;" +
   "left:0;" +
    "top:0;" +
    "background-color:#444455;" +
    "color:white;" +
     "text-align:center;font-size:20px;" +
     "'>Loading</div>";
       var GUIPanel = document.getElementById("block_div");
       GUIPanel.style["visibility"] = "hidden";
        document.body.innerHTML += blocking_div;
} </script>

Comment: can you update your question and post your aspx and code behind? i wanna try to debug it, if you are allowed to post it of course...

Comment: your code seems to run fine for me... is it possible that something on your aspx page blocks the control from posting back? can you try to create an empty aspx web form (page) and stick your custom control there to see if it works on its own

Comment: Marked your answer, since you helped me a lot. Couldn't get it running on an empty aspx page either, but that's my fault.

Comment: thanks man, sorry i couldnt help more. you could try however running the code natively in an aspx page and not via custom control, see if it works and if u absolutely have to/want to, try migrating the code to a custom control